# How to make if statement in Makefile based on platform?

Tags: c++, linux, assembly, makefile, arm64

I am having trouble with crypto wallet, which does not probably matter that much. The issue is that makefile contains files which is used for x86 architecture and I have AARCH64 files, but can't seem to find a way, how to deal with that...

So I would like to change, based on platform(in this case x86), this:

```
  crypto/randomx/jit_compiler_x86.cpp 
  crypto/randomx/jit_compiler_x86.hpp 
  crypto/randomx/jit_compiler_x86_static.asm 
  crypto/randomx/jit_compiler_x86_static.hpp 
  crypto/randomx/jit_compiler_x86_static.S
```

to this (when AARCH64):

```
  crypto/randomx/jit_compiler_a64.cpp
  crypto/randomx/jit_compiler_a64.hpp
  crypto/randomx/jit_compiler_a64_static.hpp
  crypto/randomx/jit_compiler_a64_static.S
```

So is there any way, how to do that in more elegant way, then merge those cpp/hpp/s files together*, just in Makefile?

*Well I don't think that would work, because x86 implementation has one more file.

Another issue is that it creates dependency files in form of *.PO or *PLO files, which...where are they from, they are created on the fly by compiler.

Any than in the end of Makefile is stated this:

```
crypto/randomx/libbitcoinconsensus_la-jit_compiler_x86.lo:  \
    crypto/randomx/$(am__dirstamp) \
    crypto/randomx/$(DEPDIR)/$(am__dirstamp)
```

Which probably can cause some problems, because it has x86 in it and it's some temporary *.lo file, which I too don't know where in compiling process are those files introduced.

So is there any way, how to solve this? If there is need to have separate make file, that's not a problem, if I know how to differentiate (by code) between them. I am compiling linux, so I guess in configure.ac there is a way to do that or in autogen.sh or stuff like this, which there are for setting environment.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: You could write code in the makefile to detect the architecture and store the result (either `x86_64` or `aarch64`) in a Make variable, then construct the filenames accordingly. Which part of this do you need help with?

Comment: Most likely both, because this is totaly new for me. And so far code was written to be architecture agnostic or generic is probably better word and now it has to be able to differentiate. Thanks!

Comment: You're trying to do too many new things at once. If you want to learn Make, you must start with simpler exercises, and if you want to get this makefile working quickly, you had better hand it off to someone who's already handy with build systems.

Comment: So well, let's say the second part. First part I figure out. I already have the Make variable. Now the if statement, if you can please shows on some example.

Comment: Note that most `make` implementations support some sort of control structure.  Refer to the manual of yours for details.

Comment: Well what is the issue, to just leave simple example of this. Since I am struggling with some lead, in work which I need to done. If I would find that in manual, I would not be asking here, I hope that's clear. Also if this would be common type of thing, it would probably be here multiple times, but I have not found anything. So thanks in advance.

Comment: I can help you, but I need to know which make implementation you use first.  Also, please @-mention me in the future so I get notified of your response.

Comment: @fuz I don't see that, since I normally got what I need without asking : ) Anyway, I am having an issue, with whole chain of configure.ac to passing up the this to makefile.am, makefile itself, fully generated, I can edit with no issues, but the syntax does not seems to be consitent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've given a list of file names and not indicated how you use them, so I'll assume you're assigning them to variables.

We can start with a simple [conditional](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Conditionals):

```
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),x86_64)
  do something
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),aarch64)
  do something else
endif
```

Crudely, we could do this:

```
ifeq ($(PLATFORM),x86_64)
  SOURCE := crypto/randomx/jit_compiler_x86.cpp
  HEADER := crypto/randomx/jit_compiler_x86.hpp
  ASM := crypto/randomx/jit_compiler_x86_static.asm
  STATIC_HEADER := crypto/randomx/jit_compiler_x86_static.hpp
  STATIC_SOURCE := crypto/randomx/jit_compiler_x86_static.S
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),x86_64)
  ...likewise for a64...
endif
```

That would work, but it would be highly redundant. We can improve it:

```
BASE := crypto/randomx/jit_compiler

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),x86_64)
  BASE := $(BASE)_x86
endif

ifeq ($(PLATFORM),aarch64)
  BASE := $(BASE)_a64
endif

SOURCE := $(BASE).cpp
HEADER := $(BASE).hpp
ASM := $(BASE)_static.asm
STATIC_HEADER := $(BASE)_static.hpp
STATIC_SOURCE := $(BASE)_static.S
```